# Was Kumārila Bhaṭṭa the first to argue that the Vedas were apauruṣeya (authorless)?

Tags: vedas, history, philosophy, purva-mimamsa

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kum%C4%81rila_Bha%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADa#Criticism_of_Buddhism):

> 2. Every extant school held some scripture to be correct. To show that the Veda was the only correct scripture, Bhaṭṭa **ingeniously** said that "the absence of an author would safeguard the Veda against all reproach" (apauruṣeya).

Does this make Kumārila the first Indian philosopher to argue that Vedas are    apauruṣeya? What did mīmāṃsakas before him think of the Vedas?